# Call python function from javascript which is written in python file

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7

I have python code which will record audio for some moment and save it on laptop. I need to know how can i embed python and html so that there will be 3 buttons record, stop and download having onclick functionality calling python function from javascript.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the clients, the python file is (presumably) in your server. So you can't do it directly. But you can use AJAX to connect to the server, and let the server run the python file.

Comment: I went through some answers saying I have to use ajax for calling python code but I am not able to understand it fully. I need some guidance or any link from where I can understand it fully.

Comment: Since the Python code, presumably, requires access to the microphone on the client computer, Ajax won't help you.